# updated error but repo is not in the sources.list?

Tags: updates, snap

I installed a small program, "speedtest-clt" It's a snap but it's old not touched in 2 years.

It works well enough, but when I update my system it's causing issues.

```
Err:8 https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu lunar Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:1f1c:2e5:6901:14d4:52d6:1cd1:60f8 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

OK I can live without this program, so I uninstall it but the issue remains. I checked the sources.list and it's not there. but I still get this error. The program is not in snap list.
As it stands it's blocking updates.

System info: Ubuntu Mate 23.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: You mention checking sources; what did you check?  Did you only check the main sources? or the additional directory where sources added post-install are added as well?

Comment: I looked at  /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: RESOLVED I found reference to repo in /etc/apt/sources/list.d Remove it and my system updates as expected without error.

Comment: The main sources.list file is intended for Ubuntu repositories (ie. official only)..  All sources added by users post-install belong in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which is empty on a clean install - ie. that's where you should look for anything added via `sudo add-apt-repository` etc.  A quick look at your post shows a non-Ubuntu URL & source  (*so would only be in main sources.list in error*)

Answer (score 0):

This error isn't as informative and one would like. I ran into the exact issue with speedtest-cli and a few other packages. I always resorted to removing the package and the reference in the sources.list.d, until I finally got frustrated enough to take a little more time to look into the issue.

What this error actually means is that the release you have **lunar** does not exist in the package repository. So, you can just remove it and wait until it does have a package for your release, or you can go to the repository and look at what releases they do have.

So for the speedtest-cli I went to https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ and with a bit of clicking around I found that there was not a version for **mantic**, but there was one for **jammy** so I went ahead and gave that a try. So far there are no issues.

updating:

```
deb [signed-by=...] https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu/ mantic main
```

to

```
deb [signed-by=...] https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu/ jammy main
```

> As a side note, using a previous version of a package is something you
> should do at your own risk. If you get a long list of missing
> dependencies or if the install fails, it's best to bail and wait for
> an updated version of the package.